# get const char from nsdictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, char, nsdictionary

I am trying to read `const char *` from an `nsdictionary`

so far I have tried

```
NSLog(@"input1 %s",(const char*)inInputData);
NSMutableDictionary * myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSValue* inputData = [NSValue value:&inInputData withObjCType:@encode(const char)];
[myDict setObject:inputData forKey:@"inInputData"];
NSValue* readVal= [NSValue value:[myDict valueForKey:@"inInputData"] withObjCType:@encode(const char)];
NSLog(@"input2 %@",[myDict valueForKey:@"inInputData"]);
NSLog(@"readVal1 %s",(const char*)readVal);
NSLog(@"readVal2 %s",(const char*)[myDict valueForKey:@"inInputData"]);
```

Results not matching

```
input1 !ã”—g¯ı0ã#àc†©Ä.2Ö£≤Áï7ª˚óm«Ûàut,‰aG≈ÈÜßx:◊Ætc´Ü£ªhg)8ÁÀ £Ø-<3©ô8>§
!…¨ÕøF∆‚∏0'Ñ&,œ#∏?Ô
input2 <9d>
readVal1 `+#
readVal2 `+#
```

How can I get the input1 value correctly from the dict ?

Comment: Does `inInputData` represent a null-terminated C string, or is it a random array of bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `const char` as type, while the reference to input data is of type `const char *`.

`const char *` is used for C strings or binary dara. In the first case you should convert it to an instance of `NSString`.

But in your case it is obviously used for binary data. In such a case you should convert it to an instance of `NSData`.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:inInputData length:youShouldReallyKnowThat];
```

Since instances of `NSData` are instance objects, you can store them into a dictionary.

Comment: isn't length should be `sizeof(inInputData)` ?

Comment: No, this is the size of a pointer. Where do you get it from? If it is no `\0`-terminated string, you need an extra length information.

Comment: An audio callback `- (void)handleAudioPackets:(const void *)inInputData
 numberBytes:(UInt32)inNumberBytes
 numberPackets:(UInt32)inNumberPackets
 packetDescriptions:(AudioStreamPacketDescription *)inPacketDescriptions`

Comment: Hmmm, what does `inNumberBytes` mean?

Comment: I think answer for the length is  `inPacketDescriptions[0].mDataByteSize` because of packet descriptions.